# Does the answer need to be upvoted within 12 hours to qualify for the Illiminator badge?

Tags: support, badges, up-votes

The [Illuminator](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/help/badges/136/illuminator) gold badge description says:

> Edit and answer 500 questions (both actions within 12 hours, answer score > 0)

If you post an answer and edit the question, but then the answer goes unvoted for a day, but then is upvoted the next day (i.e. well over 12 hours later), would it then qualify for the Illuminator badge because the edit and the answer were both within 12 hours of each other, or would it not qualify because the question score was not > 0 within those 12 hours?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes; only the edit needs to be within 12 hours of the answer. The moment of the upvote (actually, the score being > 0) doesn't matter.

> Let's say that you answer something, and:
>
> - You edit the question 12 hours before or after answering it. This allows you to edit now, answer later — or answer now and edit later, when you have the time.
> - Your edit isn't rolled back, or outright rejected if it was a suggested edit
> - The question is not closed for any reason, even simply being a duplicate
> - Your answer has a score of 1 or higher

Source: [New three-tiered badge idea: Explainer →Refiner → Illuminator](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/239898/295232)